# What simple function $f(i)$ produces an evenly distributed pseudorandom output for $i \in [1, 2, ...)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, random-functions

I'm looking for a transformation $N \to S$ where $N$ is natural numbers sequence, whereas $S$ is an infinite pseudorandom sequence that doesn't end up with a repeating pattern and has a uniform distribution in some specified range, say $[0, r)$. Desirably the output of the function $f$ to be an integer.

Some analog could be the [Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) for calculating a specific digit of $\pi$ . The goal is to find a simple solution in terms of computational complexity.

Searching through `StackExchange`, I found [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24388/what-simple-functions-return-equally-distributed-random-values-in-an-arbitrary-g). Unfortunately, the answer doesn't satisfy me since I don't want to use Linear congruential generator. I don't want to depend on a previous result when doing calculations. The function $f$ should solely rely on its parameter $i$. And also the sequence $S$ needs to be non-periodical.

Comment: I do not understand what the term "reflection" has to do with this. -- Also, you *can* compute the linear congruential generator without depending on previous results. Simply compute $f(x)=ax+b\bmod m$ afresh for each new $x$. It is just a lot easier and faster to compute $f(x)$ if you already know $f(x-1)$ (and you do not even need to now the infinite precision integer $x$)

Comment: Doesn't $f(x) = ax + b$ mod $m$ eventually repeats itself, do it?

Comment: would word 'transformation' work better than 'reflection'?

Answer (score 1):

If all you care about is aperiodicity and the uniform distribution of values of $f(i)$ (as opposed to the joint distribution of tuples of values like $(f(i),f(i+1))$) you should be content with the [equidisribution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) of Weyl.  Examples like $$f(i)=\lfloor r (\pi i \bmod 1)\rfloor$$
or
$$f(i)=\lfloor r (\sqrt 2 i \bmod 1)\rfloor$$
do the trick.

Abandoning Weyl's theorem, you could use a recipe like  $$f(i) = (i+k)\bmod r \text{ for $i$ in the range } r^{k-1}\le i < r^k,$$
which is to say
$$f(i) = (i+\lfloor \log_r (rk)\rfloor) \bmod r,$$
which can be computed by examining the base $r$ representation of $i$ and not evaluating the logarithm directly.

Or, for another example in this vein, if $i$ has base $r$ representation $i=\sum_k b_k r^k$ for $0\le b_k<r$, to let $f(i)=\left(\sum_k b_k\right) \bmod r$.  For instance, if $r=2$ this is the parity of the binary digits in the base 2 representation of $i$.  These examples are   especially easy to compute and   not periodic in the precise sense of the word.

All of the above use the particular  definition of "uniformly distributed" that is explained in the cited article.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer is correct, however I forgot to mention that using an irrational number is prohibited since precise calculating of them for a *very* long $i$ is actually the problem I'm trying to avoid :)

Comment: My third suggestion does not involve irrationals, but I'm sure you'll come up with some objection to it,  of the form that your stated conditions are not your real conditions.

Comment: You're right. It looks like the third option eventually will lead to a self-repeating pattern for any rational $k$, won't it? Still I will doublecheck it when I have an opportunity.

Comment: I don't think you understood my 3d example.  I have rewritten it.